# Check if numbers in a comma-separated string are odd or even

Tags: python, string, for-loop

I need to write a program which checks whether each number on a comma separated string is even or odd.

I have to do it with a `for` loop, the code I have is this:

```
getallen = '12, 3, 7, 25, 771, 45, 6, 98, 55, 546'

for number in getallen:
    if number %2 == 0:
        print(f'{int(number)} is even')
    else:
        print(f'{int(number)} is odd')
```

The output should be something like this:

```
12 is even
3 is odd
7 is odd etc etc.
```

Answer (score 1):

Your code is not working because `getallen` is a string, not an array. You need to convert it to an array first with `getallen = getallen.split(',')`

Answer (score 1):

Matt is right that you're iterating over a string, and not an array, but after splitting you also need to convert each value to a number. There's a couple ways to do this:

You can use `map` to convert each item of the array to a number using `int`:

```
for number in map(int, getallen.split(',')):
    if number %2 == 0:
        print(f'{int(number)} is even')
    else:
        print(f'{int(number)} is odd')
```

Or you can convert each number as you test it:

```
for number in getallen.split(','):
    if int(number) %2 == 0:
        print(f'{int(number)} is even')
    else:
        print(f'{int(number)} is odd')
```

Both of these will yield:

```
12 is even
3 is odd
7 is odd
25 is odd
771 is odd
45 is odd
6 is even
98 is even
55 is odd
546 is even
```

Answer (score 0):

Your string is a tuple literal, so you can just use [`ast.literal_eval`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/ast.html#ast.literal_eval) to safely convert it to a tuple of integers. This can be directly used in your `for` loop.

```
import ast
getallen = '12, 3, 7, 25, 771, 45, 6, 98, 55, 546'

for number in ast.literal_eval(getallen):
    if number %2 == 0:
        print(f'{int(number)} is even')
    else:
        print(f'{int(number)} is odd')
```

Comment: Using the Python AST to compile this code to a Python tuple seems a bit overkill. FWIW I thought this was safe too, but the documentation warns it is even possible to crash the Python interpreter with a sufficiently large/complex string due to stack depth limitations in Python’s AST compiler...

Comment: Constructing a tuple literal that is large enough to exceed Python's C stack is left as an exercise to the reader.

Comment: I'm just saying you need to be careful not to automatically assume this approach is safe in similar situations. If someone has control over the string that is supplied, a malicious attacker might see that "exercise" as a fun challenge.

Comment: For me, this is enough to crash it: `'[[[[[[[[[[[[[[[[[[[[[[[[[[[[[[[[[[[[[[[[[[[[[[[[[[[[[[[[[[[[[[[[[[[[[[[[[[[[[[[[[[[[[[[[[[[[[[]'`

Comment: @Elijan9 tbf... that's not a valid literal

Comment: @Nick: It is if you add more closing brackets, but this is enough to crash it. Even if you add the same amount of closing brackets, the Python AST compiler already crashes when parsing the first closing bracket. My point is, you don't need that many characters to crash the AST compiler.

Comment: @Elijan9 The string you have provided appears to be totally fine to recover from. It will throw a ``MemoryError`` but not crash the interpreter. Constructing an input that throws *some* exception is absolutely trivial for most cases, such as ``10.0,`` or ``(10, 12)`` to "crash" the ``map(int, ...)`` pattern.

Comment: (It's the extra AST compiler that crashes and throws the MemoryError to the regular Python interpreter.) Throwing an exception on 10.0 when using map(int, ...) is behavior as specified, you expect the input to be integer values, split by ','. Using eval_literal is like using a table saw to cut a paper, it supports a much more extensive syntax than is necessary and isn't necessarily safer...

Comment: @Elijan9 I think you have made your point that you consider ``ast.literal_eval`` overkill already. I won't object that it buys *simplicity of use* at the *cost of computational overhead*. However, I have no idea what else you are trying to point out. "you expect the input to be integer values, split by ','" is a perfectly fine situation for ``ast.literal_eval`` as well. Note that ``ast.literal_eval`` being safe doesn't mean that ``map(int, ...)`` isn't.